# One-to-many MVC Individual User Accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net mvc with the individual user accounts template where i try to make an one to many relationship from User to Items.

In a project without the individual user account template i can simply do the following:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

}
```

And

```
  public class Item
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Problem is that i cannot find a complete model for the User (ApplicationUser) in the Individual user account template. So i dont know how to add the Items to the User and generate a controller for the User (In the individual user template)

Comment: Check your spelling and grammar, please.

Answer (score 0):

From the template in the Models folder, in IdentityModels:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    // Add here ..
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Using Identity ties in the `ApplicationUser` model this way. You can change the name `ApplicationUser` to `User` here as well, provided all other references to `ApplicationUser` are also updated.

Comment: Thanks, i got the foreign key in my database. However i got an error from my ItemController: 'Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets 'ApplicationUsers' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type 'WebProject.Models.ApplicationUser'.'

Comment: Sounds like you've got two instances of "User". Using Identity for authentication, the "User", whatever it is called, must inherit from "IdentityUser". The code given in the answer IS the "User" (in this case, called ApplicationUser). I would try removing your (presumably other) User class and just use the above class (ApplicationUser) until things are established, and then, if you want, change the name to "User" and move it to where you want. The key thing is that the "User" (only one class, not two) must inherit from IdentityUser.

Comment: ... just replicate what you have in your other User class (in terms of relationships and other fields) into the code above, remove your other instance of User, and try again.

Comment: Nice. Glad it helped :-)